# Suddenly new URLs with "table/"?

Tags: url, joomla, categories, blogs, article

I'm running a simple site based on Joomla. The SEF URLs are defined by SH404SEF and look like `https://[domain]/[category]/[sub category]/[article title alias].html`. In some cases there is a 1-to-1 relationship between category and article but in some cases one category has several articles.

Suddenly I have URLs requested following `https://[domain]/table/[category]/[sub category]/`. Not only does these new URLs in some cases create 404s, they also view my articles in the wrong way and when there is not a 1-to-1 relationship between category and article the link adds several articles on one page.

The correct non-SEF URL ends with `&view=article` and the new, uncorrect non-SEF URL ends with `&view=category`. I have no `table/` in my correct URLs, neither in any internal link, in the articles' html code, in menu items nor in my sitemap.xml. I've discussed this with the few extension providers I am using and none of them see their extension as doing this request new.

1. Is there any way to find out what is making these requests?
2. I cannot make a redirect for these URLs since all of them do not
   correspond to one article, but several. Can you see any risk with
   making a rewrite rule that puts a 410 on all URLs that starts with
   `table/`?

Comment: You may receive some/more/better support at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks! Will do that!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a misconfiugration in sh404SEF. Here's what to do:

- Login to the backend of your Joomla site
- Go to the sh404SEF configuration
- Set the field "Insert Content Table Name" to "No"
- Flush all URLs and clear your Joomla cache

This should do it.

Comment: itoctopus, thanks for your response! 

Yes, that would get rid of the "table" URLs but not my problem since these list views would still be requested, shown and indexed as I've understood it. 

I would like to get rid of the category lists, that is not how I want my site to be viewed.